# Search bar - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'match'

Tags: php, mysql

Привет, я пытаюсь использовать поисковую бар `match for goods_id or name`, но когда я использую оба B `match()` я получаю эту проблему

> "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'match'" `name` - utf8_general_ci и FULLTEXT index `goods_id` - primary key AUTO INCRE. code: mysql:

```
function search(){
    $search = clear($_GET['search']);
    $result_search = array();

if(mb_strlen($search, 'UTF-8') < 1){
$result_search['notfound'] = "<div class='error'>min. 1 Letters</div>";
}else{
$query = "SELECT goods_id, name, img, price, hits, new, sale
FROM goodsbase
WHERE MATCH(goods_id, name) AGAINST('{$search}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND 
visible='1'";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
while($row_search = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
$result_search[] = $row_search;
}
}else{
$result_search['notfound'] = "<div class='error'>NO MATCH!!!</div>";
}
}

return $result_search;
}

CREATE TABLE `goodsbase` (  `goods_id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  `img` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  `goods_brandid` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,  `anons` text NOT NULL,  `content` text NOT NULL,  `visible` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', `new` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  `price` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  `date` date NOT NULL,  `img_slide` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`goods_id`),  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`)) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут два варианта:

1. Логичный - убрать good_id из MATCH - тогда поиск будет вестись только по name (он же имеет FULLTEXT индекс - верно?).
2. Фанатичный - изменить collations для name с UTF-8 на latin_general_ci. Но тогда с высокой вероятностью слетит кодировка в name.

И покажите  "show create table goodsbase;"

Comment: я знаю, что если я удалию good_id или name, это сработает, но я хочу использовать оба

Comment: Ну тут все хотят мира на земле и счастья всем и сразу. У вас good_id - int? Какой-же fulltext-поиск вы хотите по INTEGR-у??? Если в $search будет передаваться id товара, то стоит переписать sql:

    SELECT goods_id, name, img, price, hits, new, sale FROM goodsbase
    WHERE ( MATCH(name) AGAINST('{$search}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) or good_id={$search} ) AND visible='1'

Comment: при поиске получаю эту проблему 
Unknown column 'testsearch' in 'where clause'
но на goods_id, это работает

Comment: SELECT goods_id, name, img, price, hits, new, sale FROM goodsbase
WHERE ( MATCH(name) AGAINST('{$search}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) or good_id='{$search}' ) AND visible='1'

Comment: Ну вот может быть мира и для этого запроса, работает отлично, большое спасибо :)